# Classification of odd primes

Tags: number-theory, irreducible-polynomials

I'm doing a question, which asks to prove $x^4+1$ is not irreducible in any field of polynomials over  finite fields.

According to the hint, there're three cases. First, there exists $a$ such that $a^2=-1$; secondly, there exists $b$, $b^2=2$; finally, $c$ such that $c^2=-2$. I managed to find 3 proper factorizations under these three cases, and the final step should be that one of these cases always hold for any odd prime(p=2 is trivial).

I found some answers to this question in the site, but none of them explained why these 3 cases cover all odd prime numbers. So this is not a duplicate question

Comment: Should your first case be $a^2=-1$?  But in that case, just think about it.  Suppose neither $-1$ nor $2$ are squares.  What does that tell you about $-2$?

Comment: As I understand, if neither -1 nor 2 are squares, then p-1 and 2 aren't square mod p. But I have no idea how to proceed after it.

Comment: Then you need to read about quadratic residues.  It is a basic fact that the product of two non-residues is a residue.  Any introductory reference should go over this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $p=3$, this is trivial.

If $p\geq 5$, this is because the quotient group $\mathbb{F}_p^\times/\mathbb{F}_p^{\times 2}$ has order $2$.

IfHence amongst the three distinct classes of $-1,2,-2$ modulo $p$ (they are distinct since $p\geq 5$) , you have at least one which becomes trivial in the quotient group by the pigeonhole principle, meanning that at least one of your three integers is a square modulo $p$.

To prove the above claim, you can look at the morphism $\bar{x}\in\mathbb{F}_p^\times\mapsto \bar{x}^2\in \mathbb{F}_p^{\times 2}$.

This morphism is surjective, and the kernel is $\{\pm\bar{1}\}$ since $\mathbb{F}_p$ is a field. Hence the factorisation theorem tells you that $\mathbb{F}_p^\times/\{\pm \bar{1}\}\simeq   \mathbb{F}_p^{\times 2},$ so playing with cardinalities shows that $\vert \mathbb{F}_p^\times/\mathbb{F}_p^{\times 2}\vert =2$.

Alternaltively, you could use the nontrivial fact that $\mathbb{F}_p^\times$ is cyclic of order $p-1$. If $\bar{u}$ is a generator, then $\mathbb{F}_p^{\times 2}$ is generated bu $u^2$, which has order $\dfrac{p-1}{2}$ (because $2\mid p-1$).